# How do I email the stringbuilder class output using C#

Tags: c#, email, web-config, stringbuilder

I integrated some logging using the stringbuilder class and I would like to email the error to the site admin.  I am storing the email address in the web.config like so `add key="siteAdmin" value="test@test.com"`

The string is built...

```
StringBuilder errMsg = new StringBuilder();
errMsg.AppendLine();
errMsg.AppendLine("*************************");
errMsg.AppendLine("TimeStamp: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
errMsg.AppendLine(errorMessage);
errMsg.AppendLine("*************************");
sw.WriteLine(errMsg.ToString());
```

Surely I'm not the first person to try this but I can't find any resources.  Please help.

Comment: You really can't find *any* resources on how to send an email?  I find that rather unlikely.  A simple web search provides *lots* of information on how to send an email in C#.

Comment: You need to google something like "Send email C#" and then if you have any questions, ask them.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing some concepts. You don't email a stringbuilder. You build a string with a stringbuilder, then email that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vladimir Arustamian for the research pointer...this is my solution...

```
                    StringBuilder errMsg = new StringBuilder();
                errMsg.AppendLine();
                errMsg.AppendLine("*************************");
                errMsg.AppendLine("TimeStamp: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                errMsg.AppendLine(errorMessage);
                errMsg.AppendLine("*************************");
                sw.WriteLine(errMsg.ToString());


                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                message.To.Add(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteAdmin"]);
                message.Subject = "Failure";
                message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("support@support.com");
                message.Body = errMsg.ToString();
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.support.com");
                smtp.Send(message);
```